# converting a complex array into json in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, tree, treeview

Basically I want to convert an Excel Data into a complex JSON. So far, I've converted the excel data into array of rows like below. First array will always be the headings of the table.

```
const row = [["rule", "key_phrase", "doc_type", "doc_priority", "section_title"],
["approval related", "approved", "assessment report", 1, "4. Recommendations, outcome"],
["prime designation", "prime,prime designation", "assessment-report", 1, "1. Background information on the procedure, 1.1. Submission of the dossier"],
["single-arm trials", "single-arm, single arm, single, arm", "NDA", 2, "5.1 Pharmaco dymnamic properties, Clinical Efficacy"],
["single-arm trials", "single-arm, single arm, single, arm", "NDA", 2, "CLINICAL/STATISTICAL/PHARMACOVIGILANCE, Clinical Program"]]
```

[image]

And now I want to convert that array into a JSON. Every comma `,` separated values should go into the same key. **For eg. key_phrase: ["prime", "prime designation"]**.

So from the above excel data, the first JSON object should be something like this:

```
{
  "biz_rules": [
    {
      "rule": "approval related",
      "key_phrase": [
        "approved"
      ],
      "doc": [
        {
          "type": "assessment-report",
          "priority": 1,
          "sections": [
            {
              "title_keywords": [
                "4. Recommendations",
                "outcome"
              ],
              "content_keywords": [
                "marketing authorization"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "rule": "prime designation",
      "key_phrase": [
        "prime",
        "prime designation"
      ],
      "doc": [
        {
          "type": "assessment-report",
          "priority": 1,
          "sections": [
            {
              "title_keywords": [
                "1. Background information on the procedure",
                "1.1. Submission of the dossier"
              ],
              "content_keywords": [
                "prime"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "rule": "single-arm trials",
      "key_phrase": [
        "single-arm",
        "single arm",
        "single",
        "arm"
      ],
      "doc": [
        {
          "type": "NDA",
          "priority": 2,
          "sections": [
            {
              "title_keywords": [
                "5.1 Pharmacodynamic properties",
                "Clinical efficacy"
              ],
              "content_keywords": [
                "single-arm trials"
              ]
            },
            {
              "title_keywords": [
                "CLINICAL/STATISTICAL/PHARMACOVIGILANCE",
                "Clinical Program"
              ],
              "content_keywords": [
                "single-arm trials"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "assessment-report",
          "priority": 1,
          "sections": [
            {
              "title_keywords": [
                "5. Clinical efficacy ",
                "2.5.2. Main studies"
              ],
              "content_keywords": [
                "single-arm trials"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "Clinical trials",
          "priority": 2,
          "sections": [
            {
              "content_keywords": [
                "single-arm trials"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "press-release",
          "priority": 2,
          "sections": [
            {
              "content_keywords": [
                "single-arm trials"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "press-releases",
          "priority": 2,
          "sections": [
            {
              "content_keywords": [
                "single-arm trials"
              ]
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "media-releasess",
          "priority": 2,
          "sections": [
            {
              "content_keywords": [
                "single-arm trials"
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
]}
```

Ignoring **content_keywords**. The rules are uniquely divided as per sections. So every **title_keywords** inside the sections would be separate rule in excel.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with

```js
const valueToCsv = text => (text.indexOf(', ') > 0) ? text.split(', ') : text;
const newArr = arr.slice(1).map(row => ({
    rule: valueToCsv(row[0]),
    key_phrase: valueToCsv(row[1]),
    doc: [{
        type: valueToCsv(row[2]),
        priority: parseInt(row[3]),
        sections: [
            {
                title_keywords: valueToCsv(row[4])
            }
        ]
    }]
}));

console.log(JSON.stringify(newArr));
```

this code.

Comment: Thanks. Its totally working as I said. But there is a small change that i wanted. Is there a short way how we can check if the rule is already present then append the data in the same rule instead of a different object in the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with following:

```js
const data = [["rule", "key_phrase", "doc_type", "doc_priority", "section_title"],
["approval related", "approved", "assessment report", 1, "4. Recommendations, outcome"],
["prime designation", "prime,prime designation", "assessment-report", 1, "1. Background information on the procedure, 1.1. Submission of the dossier"],
["single-arm trials", "single-arm, single arm, single, arm", "NDA", 2, "5.1 Pharmaco dymnamic properties, Clinical Efficacy"],
["single-arm trials", "single-arm, single arm, single, arm", "NDA", 2, "CLINICAL/STATISTICAL/PHARMACOVIGILANCE, Clinical Program"]]

data.shift()
const obj = data.map(e => {
  return {
    rule: e[0],
    key_phrase: e[1],
    doc: {
      doc_type: e[2],
      doc_priority: e[3],
    },
    section_title: e[4],
  }
})
```